# Factor Levels in R

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

I have this vector:

```
traits <- c("resid.mean.EXT"   ,        "resid.q75.EXT"       ,     "resid.median.red"      ,   "resid.q75.red"    ,        "resid.median.yellow" ,    
            "resid.q75.yellow"  ,       "resid.mean.norm.EXT"   ,   "resid.q75.norm.EXT" ,      "resid.mean.norm.yellow"   ,"resid.median.norm.yellow",
            "resid.q75.norm.yellow"   , "resid.iqr.EXT"        ,    "resid.iqr.red"    ,        "resid.iqr.yellow"  ,       "resid.q90.EXT"   ,        
            "resid.q90.norm.red"  ,     "resid.q90.norm.yellow"   , "resid.var.EXT"     ,       "resid.q25.TOF"     ,       "resid.q25.norm.yellow" )
```

There are 20 unique strings in the vector traits, however there are 4 unique classes of traits :

```
classes <- c("EXT", "red", "TOF", "yellow")
```

The classes are determined by the last word for each element in the `traits` vector.

I would like to make the character vector `traits` into factors with 4 levels based on what class they are in.

Thanks for the help!

***EDIT*** There seems to have been some confusion. To clarify, I would like to make `traits` into a factor vector with 4 levels, corresponding to which class that belong to, which is determined as described above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions and the `sub` function, e.g.:

```
## this will replace the whole string in traits with the content after the last dot
cl <- sub(".*\\.([A-Za-z]+)$", "\\1", x=traits)
factor(cl)
# [1] EXT    EXT    red    red    yellow yellow EXT    EXT    yellow yellow yellow EXT    red    yellow EXT    red    yellow EXT    TOF    yellow
# Levels: EXT red TOF yellow
```

Comment: This gives me a vector of factors with levels corresponding to the classes. I want to keep the original vector `traits` though and give it 4 factor levels based on `classes`. Does this difference make sense?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The `levels` of a `factor` are almost `unique(factorelements)`.

Comment: I was thinking it could work using something along the lines of `factor(traits, levels = c(grepl("TOF", traits),grepl("EXT",traits),grepl("red", traits),grep("yellow",traits)))`But this doesn't work. I thought I might have been doing something wrong with the `grepl` function

Comment: A minimal not working example: `factor(c("A1", "A2", "B1"), levels = c("A", "A", "B"))`; but see @akrun's answer for a workaround using the names.

Comment: @user2813055: What you request is not possible with factors. The levels are a character vector and the values are integer indices into those levels, so you cannot have levels with sub-levels or sub values. You will need to either make a new class that has an attribute vector as long as the value vector (which is going to be a fairly involved procedure), or you need to have two parallel vectors in a dataframe (which would be very easy)